# fragments used on all APIs?

Tags: android, api

I am very new to fragments and I was wanting to make apps that work across all platforms.  To have fragments work for all APIs I would just need to import "android-v4 compatability packages" and this would work for pre API 11.  But would importing this also make it work for API 11+?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you would be limited to the functionality of the compatibility library which isn't as capable as the native Fragment implementation available in API 11+